# using scope in Rails custom validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-3.1

I want to apply scope limiter in my custom validation

I have this Product Model 
which has  make,model,serial_number, vin as a attributes

Now I have a custom validation to check against vin if vin is not present to check for combination of make+model+serial_number uniqueness in database something like this

> validate :combination_vin,:if => "vin.nil?"

```
def combination_vin 
  if Product.exists?(:make => make,:model => model,:serial_number => serial_number)
      errors.add(:base,"The Combination of 'make+model+serial_number' already present")
  end
end
```

I want to introduce a scope in this validator against user_id

Now I know I could easily write this to achieve same using

```
 def combination_vin
    if Product.exists?(:make => make,:model => model,:serial_number => serial_number,:user_id => user_id)
      errors.add(:base,"The Combination of 'make+model+serial_number' already present")
    end
 end
```

But out of curiosity I was thinking is there a scope validator (something like **{:scope => :user_id}**) on custom validation
so that I dont have to pass that extra **user_id** in the **exists? hash**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try :

```
validate :combination_vin , :uniqueness => { :scope => :user_id } , :if => "vin.nil?"
```